# Automate AWS instance start and stop

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mirth

I'm running a instance in amazon AWS and it runs non-stop everyday. I'm using ubuntu ec2 instance which is running Apache, Mirthconnect tool and LAMP server. I want to run this instance only on particular time duration of a day. I prefer not use any additional AWS services such as cloud-watch . Is there a way we could acheive this?.

The major purpose is for using Mirthconnect fetching data from mysql database

Comment: You can achieve this is two ways.These links will help you:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/stop-start-ec2-instances/
and


https://alestic.com/2011/11/ec2-schedule-instance/

The easiest is to handle schedule a shell script, use aws-cli to start your instance, but to do that you'll require the aws credentials.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 solutions.

[AWS Data Pipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/) - You can schedule the instance start/stop just like cron. It will cost you one hour of t1.micro instance for every start/stop

[AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) - Define a lambda function that gets triggered at a pre defined time. Your lambda function can start/stop instances. Your cost will be very minimal or $0

Write a shell script and run it as a cron job or run it on demand. The script will have `AWS CLI` command to start and stop the instance.

I used Data Pipeline for a long time before moving to Lambda. Data Pipeline is very trivial. Just paste the AWS CLI commands to stop and start instances. Lambda is more involved.

Answer (score 0):

I guess for that you'll need another machine which is on 24x7. On which you can write cron job in python using boto or any other language like bash.

I don't see how you start a instance in `stopped` state without using any other machine.

Or you can have a simple raspberry pi on at your home which does the ON-OFF work for you using AWS CLI or simple Python. How about that? ;)

Comment: I mean to say, if the instance is already running and we just need to stop at a specific time, then run the instance again. Running a shell script cron-job to stop and start another instance is a good one. But considering long-term solution use of another instance will be more likely to increase cost. Is there any other preferable way we can acheive this?

Comment: Yes It will increase cost but if you got spare rPi then you can do this. There might be other possible ways also but I am not aware of them!

Comment: and why someone would vote me down :( this ain't complete wrong approach!